# Communicate between UI and background thread

Tags: android, multithreading

Its for the first time I'm making a fairly large app and there are lots of sections in it.

I want to keep UI and background processes in different classes to avoid confusion. However, how do i communicate  among them in best possible way. I've come across few approaches till now:

1. Declaring background thread in different class and defined its onPostExecute() method in UI thread.

   ```
       new SetupDefaultFeeds(context) {
       @Override
       protected void onPostExecute(List<Feed> result) {
           default_feeds = result;

           for (Feed t : result) {
               String log = t.toString();
               Log.d("DEFAULT feed", log);
           }
           menu_btn[0].performClick();
       }
   }.execute();
   ```
2. Signalling using a flag variable between background and UI thread.
3. Thread and handler.

Are there any other ways and what is the best possible way. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Passing messages through a [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) is usually the most "Android-ish" way to do this. Trying to do all communication through flag variables is most likely going to be quite a headache.

*Edit*: Android itself doesn't provide a way for you to link the two classes together, you need to do that by hand. One way which works quite well is to create an interface for your communication and have either the UI class or background thread implement it. Then, when creating the class, you can pass a reference to the other object and communicate through the interface.

However, if you want to completely decouple the two classes, you might want to use a BroadcastReceiver instead and use it to send messages between the UI and background thread.

Comment: I knw how to do this when we have background thread and UI in same class..but I dnt knw how to do this, when background thread and UI are in different classes. Can u help me with the code !